# Bluebird promise `promisifyAll` not working - cannot read property `then`

Tags: xml-parsing, callback, promise, bluebird, node-modules

I am using a node module that uses the node callback convention. I wants to convert this module into an API using Bluebird promises. I am not getting how to do this.

Below is my node style callback function. I wants to convert it into thenable promise of bluebird.

```
var module = require('module'); // for example xml2js, or Mongoose
var parseString = xml2js.parseString; 
    parseString(xml, function (err, result) { // the regular API
      if (err) {
       console.log("Error in generation json from xml");
      } else {
       return result;
      }
    });
```

I tried this way using `PromisifyAll` but it is not working:

```
var module = Promise.promisifyAll(require('module')); // for example xml2js
xml2js.parseString(xml)
        .then(function (result) {
            console.log("result = ", result);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.err(err);
        });
```

I'm getting `then is not a function` errors. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When bluebird converts a module (like xml2js) into a promise based API using `promisifyAll` then it appends an `Async` suffix to each function name and adds that function into that object:

```
var xml2js = Promise.promisifyAll(require('xml2js')); // example: xml2js 
xml2js.parseStringAsync(xml) // NOTE THE ASYNC SUFFIX
        .then(function (result) {
            console.log("result = " + JSON.stringify(result));
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.err(err);
        });
```

When you call `parseString` without the async suffix, it calls the original callback-based function.

Comment: I was using promisifyAll with request, and it didn't require me to add the Async suffix. Is there a particular reason?

Comment: @AnthonyMayfield I think request module is by default made using promise concepts. I used .then on request without promisifying it